# Magnitude of a complex expression

Tags: complex-numbers

Is there a way to derive an expression for the magnitude of 
$$
\frac{2 + (1-2ia\lambda \sin \theta)^{1/2}}{3 + 2ia\lambda\sin\theta}
$$

I know how to do this if the square root weren't there. Any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: Multiply by conjugate and recall that $|z| = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$.

Comment: @dustin how do you get rid of the square root though?

Comment: Does this help? $
\frac{2 + (1-2ia\lambda \sin \theta)^{1/2}}{3 + 2ia\lambda\sin\theta}=\frac{2 + (1-2ia\lambda \sin \theta)^{1/2}}{(2 + (1-2ia\lambda \sin \theta)^{1/2})(2 - (1-2ia\lambda \sin \theta)^{1/2})}=\frac{1}{2 - (1-2ia\lambda \sin \theta)^{1/2}}$

Comment: @AranKomatsuzaki so is $\frac{1}{2-(1+2ia\lambda\sin\theta)^{½}}$ the conjugate of $\frac{1}{2-(1-2ia\lambda\sin\theta)^{½}}$?

Comment: @AranKomatsuzaki where did the denominator $3+2i\lambda\sin\theta$ go?

Comment: Yes. I just factored the denominator $3+2i\lambda\sin\theta$  to the two factors.

Comment: @AranKomatsuzaki got it!! Thanks!

Comment: @AranKomatsuzaki I still don't see how you can find the complex magnitude though

Comment: @AranKomatsuzaki I see it now!

Comment: @AranKomatsuzaki so the complex magnitude is $\left(\frac{1}{3 + 2ia\lambda\sin\theta}\right)^{½}$ right?

Comment: The magnitude should be real, but that's not real. So, the problem is not yet solved.

Comment: @AranKomatsuzaki that's what I thought. But that's what I get using $|z| = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$

Answer (score 0):

To determine the modulus, we need to multiple by the conjugate which is $3 - 2ia\lambda\sin(\theta)$. Now, let $w = (1 - 2ia\lambda\sin(\theta))^{1/2}$ which has a modulus of $\lvert w\rvert = \sqrt{1 + 4a^2\lambda^2\sin^2(\theta)}$ and the principle argument is $\phi = \arctan(-2a\lambda\sin(\theta))$ where $\phi\in(-\pi, \pi)$. Therefore, we can write
$$
(1 - 2ia\lambda\sin(\theta))^{1/2} = \exp(1/2(\ln\lvert w\rvert + i\phi)) =
w^{1/4}e^{i\phi/2}
$$
Now the denominator is a real number and the numerator no longer has a complex number in a square root. All you need to do is separate the real and imaginary parts so you can find the modulus of $z$
$$
\frac{(2 + \lvert w\rvert^{1/2}e^{i\phi/2})(3 - 2ai\lambda\sin(\theta))}{9+4a^2\lambda^2\sin^2(\theta)}
$$

Comment: Did you mean $(1-2ia\lambda\sin\theta)^{½} = |w|^{¼} e^{i\phi/2}$?

Comment: @user90593 it probably should be written as $\lvert w\rvert^{1/2}$ since $\lvert\cdot\rvert = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$